# curried And uncurried functions

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

**Curried**

```
add::Int->Int->Int
add x y = x+y
```

**Uncurried**

```
add1::(Int,Int)->Int
add1 (x,y)=x+y
```

I have several problems regrading **Curried** and **Uncurried** function , consider the functions above,

### Question 1

in Uncurried function input parameters are as `(Int,Int)` , so is it equalent to a input a **tuple** ? how can we differentiated that ?

### Question 2

What are the pros and cons regarding uncurried and curried functions? When and why should which be used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> in Uncurried function input parameters are as (Int,Int) , so is it equalent to a input a tuple ? how can we differentiated that ?

It's not only equivalent, but it *is* a tuple. So `add1` is a function that takes a pair (2-tuple) of Ints and returns an Int.

> Whats the pros and congs regarding uncurried and curried functions ? , and where to use them ?

As a rule of thumb, I'd say: Always use curried functions, if you don't have a good reason not to.
They have the nice feature that you can partially apply them, e.g. you can write `f = add 1`, where `f` now has the type `f :: Int -> Int` and always adds 1 to its argument.

This has many applications and is *very* common in Haskell, because it's so convenient. E.g. a function that adds 1 to all elements in a list would simply be `map (add 1)`.

Additionally the syntax is much less noisy.

Comment: Good examples of how you can use this are : "and = foldr (&&) True", "or = foldr (||) False", "sum = foldl (+) 0", "product = foldl (*) 1", "maximum = foldl1 max", "minimum = foldl1 min".

Answer (score 4):

I like @bzn's answer, but I wanted to give a few examples of where uncurried functions are useful.

Some libraries make heavy use of tuples of data.  One example is Gtk2hs, which uses a tuple `(Int, Int)` for window sizes and certain coordinates.  So when I'm working with gtk2hs, I'll often write functions in an uncurried form so I don't have to manually unpack the tuple.

Also remember that a function can only return one result.  To return more than one value, all the results need to be packed into a tuple.  `uncurry` is then useful to make compositions out of those functions.  Here's a simplified example from a project I'm working on:

```
addIndex :: MyData -> (Int, MyData)

normalize' :: Int -> MyData -> [(Int, MyData)]

normalize :: [MyData] -> [(Int, MyData)]
normalize = concatMap (uncurry normalize' . addIndex)
```

I usually prefer writing functions in a curried form, but here I needed the uncurried version of `normalize'` to compose with `addIndex`.

These are the two situations where I find an uncurried function useful.  Fortunately it's easy to convert between the two forms.

Comment: You can also generalize uncurry via TH.